# Error with layer export

Tags: qgis, layers, export

I am having problems exporting a layer in QGIS. The error message shows Export to vector file failed:

`Error: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: sqlite3_open(enedun24_planetaji.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)`

Comment: Please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/291146/276